# Is Django registration redux form open source

Tags: django, django-registration

Can we use Django registration redux form in professional website. I am confused. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [license for Django-Registration(-Redux)](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/LICENSE) is the [3-clause BSD License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause), so yes, you can use it in a commercial context.